# How do you call a function by default in the render method?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

For some reason, its not actually accessing the exercises method. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong here. Appreciate it!

```
class StartWorkout extends Component {
  state = {
    step: 0
  };

  exercises = () => {
    const { exerciselist } = this.props.selectedWorkout;
    const { step } = this.state.step;
    while (step < exerciselist.length) {
      return <StartExercise exercise={exerciselist[step]} />;
    }
  };

  render() {
    const { name } = this.props.selectedWorkout;
    const { step } = this.state;
    return (
      <>
        <ClientMenuBar title={name} />
        <Container maxWidth="xl">
          {this.exercises()}
          <div style={styles.buttonWrapper}>
            <Button
              color="inherit"
              variant="contained"
              style={styles.button}
              size="large"
            >
              Back
            </Button>
            <Button
              color="primary"
              variant="contained"
              type="submit"
              style={styles.button}
              size="large"
              onClick={() => {
                this.setState({ step: step + 1 });
              }}
            >
              Next
            </Button>
          </div>
        </Container>
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

I know its not actually going into the method because I am console logging right before i access it and right before the while loop in the function and its only calling the first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few problems here:

```
// this line is double-dereferencing 'step'
const { step } = this.state.step;

// step will be undefined here
while (step < exerciselist.length) {
  // if you're going to return this, what's the loop for?
  // (and if you don't return, this loop will never exit
  // because 'step' never changes)
  return <StartExercise exercise={exerciselist[step]} />;
}
```

Here's an updated example of how you might go about it now that I better understand what you're trying to do.

```js
class Exercises extends React.Component {
  state = {step: 0}

  render() {
const {step} = this.state;

const {workout: {exercises}} = this.props;

return (
  <div>
    <div> {exercises[step]} </div>
    <button
      disabled={step < 1}
      onClick = {() => this.setState({step: step - 1})}
    >
      Previous
    </button>

    <button
      disabled={step >= exercises.length - 1}
      onClick = {() => this.setState({step: step + 1})}
    >
      Next
    </button>
  </div>
  )
}
  }

  const workout = {
exercises: Array.from({length: 5}, (_, i) => `Exercise ${i + 1}`)
  };

  ReactDOM.render(
<Exercises workout={workout} />,
document.querySelector("#app")
  );
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#app {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

li {
  margin: 8px 0;
}

h2 {
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.done {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  text-decoration: line-through;
}

input {
  margin-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: I purposefully did that. I only want to return one item at a time, but it's not even getting to the while loop anyway for some reason

Comment: I hadn't noticed this but [Anuradha Kumari](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58037992/636077) is right about trying to destructure `{step}` from `this.state.step`, which is going to be `undefined`.

Comment: If you're only returning one at a time, what do you need a while loop for?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with the exercises method. Here you are trying to access`step` from `this.state.step`. Replace `const { step } = this.state.step;` . by `const { step } = this.state;`.

Notice the extra `step` property which you are trying to access which comes as `undefined` and `undefined < any number` is false, and hence the code inside while loop never gets executed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use constructor. Update your code like this:

```
class StartWorkout extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
       step: 0,
    };
  }
  exercises = () => {
    const { exerciselist } = this.props.selectedWorkout; 
    // The way your destructuring the state is wrong. It should be like this.
    const { step } = this.state; // not required anymore
    return exerciselist.map(item => {
        return <StartExercise exercise={item} />;
    }
  };

// Use your render function as it is.

}
```

Hope this helps!!

Comment: using constructor won't make any difference, because the constructor is optional. We can define the state as Kasey has in the question and it will work just fine.